# What's the correct way to get the latest versions of Azure Python SDK for Ubuntu?

Tags: azure

To do this I ran just ran the command

```
pip3 install azure
```

and from what I could tell this retrieved the latest versions of the various Azure modules for Python3. For example, the Postgres version was listed as 2017-12-01 and networking was 2018-08-01. However, I ran the same command from two other Ubuntu systems and on these systems the Postgres version was much older, 2017-04-30-preview.

How do I insure that the latest stable versions of the Azure SDK modules are installed when I run the pip install command on a system?

Comment: pretty weird, i guess you need to update pip first?

Comment: The version of pip impacts which versions of the packages it installs?

Comment: I checked the systems involved and sure enough the version of pip3 running on the culprit systems was 9.0.1. On the other system it's 18.0. I'm in the process now of trying to get pip3 updated on those system. It should be an easy job but it's turning out to be way more difficult than it should be. Ubuntu insists on installing 9.0.1 and version get-pip.py installs (18.1) is broken.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more trouble than it should have been, I managed to get pip3 updated on these systems and then running

```
pip3 install azure
```

installed the latest versions of the Azure modules. I didn't realize the version of pip impacts which versions of external modules it installs but apparently it plays a role.